# Need help asp.net other textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

In my project i have kept source info in dropdownlist. Like source of info: in dropdownlist three items website, Newspaper and others. If user select Others item, then only other text box should be visible otherwise should be invisible. For that i have set in page load event

lblother.visible=false;
txtother.visible=false;

And in Btnsubmit event i have written the condition like.
if(dropdownlistinfo.selectedindex==2)
{
   lblother.visible=true;
   txtother.visible=true;
}
But in my case i m not getting my desire output. Its always invisible when i am selecting Others item from drowdownlist also. Pls somebody help me where is my mistake?

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    lblother.visible = false;
    txtother.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Mehdi Though i have written your if condition its not working pls give me the alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you set Selected property of the default list item.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem Text="Website" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Newspaper"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="lblOther" runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Hide the controls in the Page Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtOther.Visible = false;
    this.lblOther.Visible = false;
}
```

Then show the controls in the button click event.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex  == 2) 
    {
        this.txtOther.Visible = true; 
        this.lblOther.Visible = true; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi its working under dropdown_selectedindex change event. For this i had to set autopostback=true in dropdownlist control. Now the problem is when i am first time running my application and selecting other item from dropdownlist Other lable and Other text box is visible, but when i select website or newspaper from drowpdownlist the other text box and lable immediately should be in visible. but its not happening. Pls solve this problem....thanks

Comment: This should work the same using the SelectedIndexChanged event. Are txtOther.Visibile = false and lblOther.Visibile = false in the page load event wrapped in a !IsPostPack, if so remove these statements from inside the block.